# ARKit - How to move object along the recognised surface?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arkit

How can I make a 3D object (a car) to move along the surface which was recognized by ARKit (Unity, C#)?

So that instead of finger tap I could use UI to manipulate the car, while the car will use the surface, recognized by ARKit, for movement and collide with it in case of any rigid body effects.

Is it possible to make it also collide with other surfaces (for example the walls)?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will allow you to tap on your object and drag to move it along a surface.  In regards to collisions, etc - make sure your objects have appropriate colliders and rigidbody's.  ARKit currently only provides horizontal surfaces, so not sure how to deal with wall collisions...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DragAlongSurface : MonoBehaviour {

  private bool holding;

  void Start () {
    holding = false;
  }

  void Update() {

    if (holding) {
      Move();
    }

    // One finger
    if (Input.touchCount == 1) {

      // Tap on Object
      if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began ) {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.GetTouch(0).position);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, 100f)) {
          if (hit.transform == transform) {
            holding = true;
          }
        }
      }

      // Release 
      if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended) {
        holding = false;
      } 
    }
  }

  void Move(){
   RaycastHit hit;
   Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.GetTouch (0).position);
   // The GameObject this script attached should be on layer "Surface"
   if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 30.0f, LayerMask.GetMask("Surface"))) {
     transform.position = new Vector3(hit.point.x,
                                      transform.position.y,
                                      hit.point.z);
    }
  }    
}
```